# Best way to create a week or day view for a calendar using GridView while getting the times right as well?

Tags: android, calendar, android-gridview

So I have decided to create my week or day views using a `GridView`. Getting an individual day or week and putting the events thats corresponds to it isn't so bad. But there is one thing I have no idea how to implement correctly. I would like to put events in the right time frame as well, down to the minute if possible. I was hoping to get some advice on how to possibly accomplish this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have a day GridView within each cell of the month GridView.  Not sure what the performance would be like though.  Perhaps it might be best to create your own Panel that overrides onMeasure & onLayout to put the events in the correct spots.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You are right, the performance might be an issue, but I could override that. I'll do some research on that and see if it'll work